# Why does [checked] not work with ngModel when used in checkbox?

Tags: angular

I was playing with ngModel in checkboxes, and ran into a situation where I found `[checked]="true"` was not working with `[(ngModel)]="select"`. Also, I was calling a function on `(change)` where I was setting the model select = true, the model changed but the view was not updated.

To fix the above two problems I used `[ngModel]="true"` instead of `[checked]` and sent `$event` to the function on `(change)` where I did `event.target.checked = true`.

Initially:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" [checked]="true" [(ngModel)]="works" (change)="func()">

func() {
    this.works = true;  // this updates the model but not view
}
```

My attempt:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheck" [ngModel]="true" [(ngModel)]="works" (change)="func($event)">

func(event) {
    this.works = true;  // this updates the model
    event.target.checked = true; //this updates the view
}
```

Comment: Try this.worked=checked

Comment: tried but no luck @MukulSharma

Comment: @MohitRajput `works = true` set on `component.ts` file not need to `[ngmodel]=true` if change the value from ts file or template reflect on both because you are using two way binding.

Comment: @Abhishek what if I need to check the checkbox on a condition. Suppose obj1={"property1":"exist" } and check the checkbox initially iff [checked]="property=='exist' ", then how will this work with two way binding [(ngModel)]

Comment: @MohitRajput check box is take Boolean value. `[checked]="property"` set property is true. In other hand you have check  `property=='exist' ` in your ts file if exist set true `this.checkeValue = true` otherwise false.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input [(ngModel)]="works" type="checkbox"/>
```

This will do two-way binding for checkbox. Therefore you don't need [checked] property.

Or use the checked property instead of ngModel,

in .html,

```
<input [checked]="works" type="checkbox" (change)="func($event)"/>
```

in .ts,

```
works: boolean;

func(e){
  if(e.target.checked){
     this.works = true;
  }
  else{
     this.works = false;
  }
  console.log(this.works);
}
```

Comment: true. I want to check the checkbox on a condition initially like if some expression equals to true, then  how will ngModel work in this scenario

Comment: The explanation of using either ``[(ngModel)]`` or ``[Checked]`` with a ``(change)`` event was very helpful. It helped me to undertand why I would want to use ``[(ngModel)]``.

Answer (score 0):

when we use a input type check with [(ngModel)] the ONLY thing you need is [(ngModel)] and a variable.

```
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="myvariable">
  <div *ngIf="myvariable">you are checked</div>
```